# Handlebars add class

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have following JSON:

```
 "daysRange": {
    "status": "UNSPECIFIED/ALL/SPECIFIED",
    "available": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "MONDAY"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "TUESDAY"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "WEDNESDAY"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "THURSDAY"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "FRIDAY"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "SATURDAY"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "SUNDAY"
      }
    ],
    "selected": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "TUESDAY"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm using handlebars like this to generate li's:

```
     <ul class="available">
        {{#each daysRange.available}}
          <li data-id="{{this.id}}">{{this.name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
     </ul>
```

**Question:** How can I add class selected to selected days? I'll appreciate is someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to massage the data before it hits the template. Mark the `selected` day in the `available` list so you can test for it during the iteration.

1. parse the JSON to an object
2. iterate over the `available` list and compare the ids to the elements in `selected`
3. something like

   ```
   if (available[i].id === selected[j].id) 
       available[i].selected = true;`
   ```

---

You can also do it with a custom helper, but this seems messier to me than just correcting your data:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isSelected', function(selected, options) {
    var ret = "";      
    if (this.id === selected[0].id) {
        ret = "selected";
    }
    return options.fn(ret);
});
```

then in your template,

```
 <ul class="available">
     {{#each daysRange.available}}
         <li data-id="{{this.id}}" class="{{#isSelected ../daysRange.selected}}{{this}}{{/isSelected}}">{{this.name}}</li>
     {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate, may be some pseudo code at least?

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with first approach. Are you sure helper will work? Don't u need to loop over ranther than doinf this `if (this.id === selected[0].id)`

Comment: I wasn't sure how many selections you would have, so I just grabbed the first one. The loop is simple though; I'm sure you can work it out.